# Java wsimport generates classes from wsdl with warning streaming-attachments

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, attachment, wsimport

I've tried to generate Java sources/classes from wsdl with wsimport, but I get some warnings on streaming-attachments operations. The class cannot contain methods to upload attachments. How can I upload an attachment?

```
<operation name="bekuldes">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://oep.hu//bekuldes"/>
        <sa:stream-attachments xmlns:sa="http://oracle.com/schemas/webservices/streaming-attachments" name="attachments"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="EJelentesException">
            <soap:fault name="EJelentesException" use="literal" encodingStyle=""/>
        </fault>
    </operation>
```

Comment: [WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "stream-attachments" (in na
mespace "http://oracle.com/schemas/webservices/streaming-attachments")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to sending an image in base64 via document literal SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817021/alternatives-to-sending-an-image-in-base64-via-document-literal-soap)